# Scrolling Through Widget in Mobile

Tags: mobile, widget, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I'm designing a mobile application using Unreal Engine. I would like to implement the "casual" scroll style with a person being able to simply swipe up using their finger so that the page will go up and not using the ScrollBox.

Do I need to implement this feature, or does the functionality already exist in Unreal Engine? If I do need to implement it, how do I do it?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this answer on UE4 AnswerHub? https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/111546/umg-scrollbox-and-ios-and-other-touch-screens.html